# sending email without user knowing

Tags: android, eclipse, email, jar, gmail

I have 2 classes mail and mainactivity and 1 xml file which contain a button, what I want is when I click on tht button , the app will send email automatically to an email address I wrote in my code, I tried this code :

mail class :

```
package com.example.emailtest;

import java.util.Date; 
import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.activation.CommandMap; 
import javax.activation.DataHandler; 
import javax.activation.DataSource; 
import javax.activation.FileDataSource; 
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap; 
import javax.mail.BodyPart; 
import javax.mail.Multipart; 
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication; 
import javax.mail.Session; 
import javax.mail.Transport; 
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage; 
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart; 



public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
   private String _user; 
   private String _pass; 

   private String[] _to ;
   private String _from; 

   private String _port; 
   private String _sport; 

   private String _host; 

   private String _subject; 
   private String _body; 

   private boolean _auth; 

   private boolean _debuggable; 

   private Multipart _multipart; 


   public Mail() { 
     _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
     _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
     _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

     _user = "lama chan"; // username 
     _pass = **********"; // password 
     _from = "lamachanz@gmail.com"; // email sent from

     _to = new String[] {"lamachanz@gmail.com"}; 
     _subject = "hi"; // email subject 
     _body = "test"; // email body 

     _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
     _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

     _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

     // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the      multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
     MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
     mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
     mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
     mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
     mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
     mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
     CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
   }  
   public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
     _user = user; 
     _pass = pass; 
   } 

   public boolean send() throws Exception { 
     Properties props = _setProperties(); 

     if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 
       Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

       MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

       msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

       InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
       for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
         addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
       } 
         msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

       msg.setSubject(_subject); 
       msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

       // setup message body 
       BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
       messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
       _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

       // adding attachment
       addAttachment("filename");//replace with file name u need

       // Put parts in message 
       msg.setContent(_multipart); 

       // send email 
       Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
       transport.connect(_host, 465,_user, _pass);
       Transport.send(msg); 

       return true; 
     } else { 
       return false; 
     } 
   } 

   public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
     BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
     DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
     messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
     messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

     _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
   } 

   @Override 
   public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
     return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
   } 

   private Properties _setProperties() { 
     Properties props = new Properties(); 

     props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

     if(_debuggable) { 
       props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
     } 

     if(_auth) { 
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
     } 

     props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
     props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
     props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
     props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 
     props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

     return props; 
   } 

   // the getters and setters 
   public String getBody() { 
     return _body; 
   } 

   public void setBody(String _body) { 
     this._body = _body; 
   } 

   // more of the getters and setters É.. 
 }
```

and my mainactivity class is :

```
package com.example.emailtest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
public Button bsend;
public Mail m;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bsend=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             Mail mail = new Mail();
                try {
                    mail.send();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }}


    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

but it did not work ! when I click on the button it will crash !

this is what I got in logcat :

```
  12-13 06:59:49.961: W/dalvikvm(3207): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/emailtest/Mail; (823)
  12-13 06:59:49.961: W/dalvikvm(3207): Link of class 'Lcom/example/emailtest/Mail;' failed
  12-13 06:59:49.961: E/dalvikvm(3207): Could not find class 'com.example.emailtest.Mail', referenced from method com.example.emailtest.MainActivity$1.onClick
  12-13 06:59:49.971: W/dalvikvm(3207): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 711 (Lcom/example/emailtest/Mail;) in Lcom/example/emailtest/MainActivity$1;
  12-13 06:59:49.971: D/dalvikvm(3207): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
  12-13 06:59:49.981: W/dalvikvm(3207): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/emailtest/Mail; (823)
  12-13 06:59:49.981: W/dalvikvm(3207): Link of class 'Lcom/example/emailtest/Mail;' failed
  12-13 06:59:49.981: D/dalvikvm(3207): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x13b3 at 0x02 in Lcom/example/emailtest/MainActivity$1;.onClick
  12-13 06:59:50.421: D/gralloc_goldfish(3207): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
  12-13 07:01:37.911: D/AndroidRuntime(3207): Shutting down VM
  12-13 07:01:37.911: W/dalvikvm(3207): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4acab90)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207): Process: com.example.emailtest, PID: 3207
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.emailtest.Mail
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at com.example.emailtest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:24)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
  12-13 07:01:37.951: E/AndroidRuntime(3207):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

can someone help me :(
I don't know what the error is !

Comment: do the code in OnCreate..instead of button click..

Comment: Clear your IDE's caches and regenerate your build files

Comment: Check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Comment: @Mitesh I tried it and when I ran the app it crashed :(

Comment: @OrhanC1 sorry I didn't understand what you meant

Comment: @LamaTatwany Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @OrhanC1 im not sure , how can I know ? x_X

Comment: @LamaTatwany What program are you using to develop with? Eclipse? IntelliJ? Notepad?

Comment: possible duplicate of [click on button then automaticly send email in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559543/click-on-button-then-automaticly-send-email-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

This class javax.mail.Authenticator belongs java SE.

There may be some super class which android doesn't supports , or is missing.

Verify that first.

Check this answer

[Send mail without Gmail using javax mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255476/send-mail-without-gmail-using-javax-mail?rq=1)